# Padding not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I'ma making a Tic-Tac-Toe game on Javascript and the 'X' and 'O' on the board are a little bit down and are not centered on the vertical axis. I've tried to fix it using padding-top or padding-bottom but it seems that they do nothing. I'm leaving the whole code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- INITIALIZE -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--CONTENT-->
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container text-center">

  <div id="title">
   TIC-TAC-TOE
  </div>

  <div id="textContainer">

  </div>



 </div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 chooseSide();
});

var playerSelect, aiSelect = "";
var turn;
var gameOn;
var xWins;
var counter = 0;
var drawGame = false;
var gridArray = [];

function chooseSide(){

 $('#textContainer').html('<p> Choose side: </p> <div class="chooseButton">X</div> <div class="chooseButton">O</div>');

 $('.chooseButton').click(function(){
  playerSelect = $(this).html();

  if(playerSelect == "X"){
   aiSelect = "O";
  } else { aiSelect = "X"; }

  iniGame();

 });
}

function iniGame(){
 $('#textContainer').fadeOut("fast", function(){
  $('#textContainer').remove();
 });

 $('body').hide().append('<div id="gridContainer"></div>').fadeIn("slow");
 $('body').hide().append('<div id="winnerContainer"> <div id="replay" class="text-center fa fa-refresh fa-3x"></div> </div>').fadeIn("slow");
 
 gameOn = true;
 turn = "player";
 resetGrid();
}

function resetGrid(){

 $('.gridElement').remove();

 for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  $('#gridContainer').append('<div class="gridElement" id="gridNumber'+i+'"></div>');
  gridArray.push('e');
 }

 console.log(gridArray);

 /*var gridElementSize = $('#gridContainer').width()/3;

 $('.gridElement').css({'width': gridElementSize, 'height': gridElementSize});*/

 $('.gridElement').click(function(e){
  handlePlayerClick(e);
 });

}

function handlePlayerClick(e){

 if(gameOn == false){

  if(xWins == true && drawGame == false){
   console.log("X Wins");
  } else if(xWins == false && drawGame == false){
   console.log("O Wins");
  } else if(xWins == false && drawGame == true){
   console.log("Its a draw");
  }

  return;

 }  else {

  if(turn == "player"){

   square = $(e.target);

   if(square.html() == ""){
    square.html(playerSelect);
    turn = "enemy";
    console.log('Player has made a move');
    checkForWin();
    if(gameOn == true){
     makeEnemyMove(); 
    }
   } else { console.log("Square taken"); } 

  } else {
   if(gameOn == true){
    makeEnemyMove(); 
   }
   console.log("Enemy's turn");
  }

 }
}

function makeEnemyMove(){
 var chooseNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
 var chooseBox = $('#gridNumber'+chooseNumber);

 if(chooseBox.html() == ''){
  chooseBox.html(aiSelect);
  checkForWin();
  turn ="player";
 } else {
  makeEnemyMove();
 }

}

function checkForWin(){


 for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  var squareVal = $('#gridNumber' + i).html();
  if(squareVal !== ''){
   counter ++;
  }
  gridArray[i] = squareVal;
 }
 console.log(counter);
 
 //--- X Checks for winning ----
 if( (gridArray[0] == 'X' && gridArray[1] == 'X' && gridArray[2] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[3] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[5] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[6] == 'X' && gridArray[7] == 'X' && gridArray[8] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'X' && gridArray[3] == 'X' && gridArray[6] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[1] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[7] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'X' && gridArray[5] == 'X' && gridArray[8] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[8] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[6] == 'X') ) 
 { 
  gameOn = false; 
  xWins = true;
  $('#winnerContainer').append('<div id="winnerText">X WINS!</div>');
 }

 //--- Y Checks for winning ----
 if( (gridArray[0] == 'O' && gridArray[1] == 'O' && gridArray[2] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[3] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[5] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[6] == 'O' && gridArray[7] == 'O' && gridArray[8] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'O' && gridArray[3] == 'O' && gridArray[6] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[1] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[7] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'O' && gridArray[5] == 'O' && gridArray[8] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[8] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[6] == 'O') )
 { 
  gameOn = false; 
  xWins = false;
  $('#winnerContainer').append('<div id="winnerText">O WINS!</div>');
 }

 if(counter == 9 && gameOn == true){
  drawGame = true;
  gameOn = false;
  console.log("Its a draw");
 } else {counter = 0;}

 if(gameOn == false && drawGame == false){
  if(xWins == true){
   console.log("X Wins");
  } else {
   console.log("O Wins");
  }
  return;
 }

}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #338f51;
 font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;


}

#title{
 color: #fbd242;
 font-size: 120px;

 margin-top: 10px;
}

#textContainer{
 color: #fbd242;
 font-size: 40px;

 margin-top: 20%;


}

.chooseButton{

 display: inline-block;

 font-size: 120px;

 border-radius: 10px;

 padding-top:10px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;


 background-color: #d81f70;
}

#gridContainer{
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;

 background-color: #ef529c;
 border-radius: 10px; 

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#gridContainer > div{

 color: #fbd242;
 font-size: 140px;
 background-color: #d81f70;

 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;

 display: inline-block;

 width: 120px; height: 120px;
 vertical-align:top;

 border: 1px solid #d81f70;
}



#replay{

 color: #fbd242;

 width: 20px;

 display:block;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- INITIALIZE -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--CONTENT-->
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container text-center">

  <div id="title">
   TIC-TAC-TOE
  </div>

  <div id="textContainer">

  </div>



 </div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a minimal working Demo

Answer (score 1):

You want to get rid of the padding and set the line-height and text alignment

```
#gridContainer > div {
    line-height: .8em;  /* something like this */
    text-align: center;
    /* rest of the code minus the padding */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to update some **CSS:*

```
.gridElement{
  display: inline-flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Here is the working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/64tu0m7w/)

**CODE:**

**Note:** run snippet code will take time to load. wait to load after clicking `run snippet code`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 chooseSide();
});

var playerSelect, aiSelect = "";
var turn;
var gameOn;
var xWins;
var counter = 0;
var drawGame = false;
var gridArray = [];

function chooseSide(){

 $('#textContainer').html('<p> Choose side: </p> <div class="chooseButton">X</div> <div class="chooseButton">O</div>');

 $('.chooseButton').click(function(){
  playerSelect = $(this).html();

  if(playerSelect == "X"){
   aiSelect = "O";
  } else { aiSelect = "X"; }

  iniGame();

 });
}

function iniGame(){
 $('#textContainer').fadeOut("fast", function(){
  $('#textContainer').remove();
 });

 $('body').hide().append('<div id="gridContainer"></div>').fadeIn("slow");
 $('body').hide().append('<div id="winnerContainer"> <div id="replay" class="text-center fa fa-refresh fa-3x"></div> </div>').fadeIn("slow");
 
 gameOn = true;
 turn = "player";
 resetGrid();
}

function resetGrid(){

 $('.gridElement').remove();

 for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  $('#gridContainer').append('<div class="gridElement" id="gridNumber'+i+'"></div>');
  gridArray.push('e');
 }

 console.log(gridArray);

 /*var gridElementSize = $('#gridContainer').width()/3;

 $('.gridElement').css({'width': gridElementSize, 'height': gridElementSize});*/

 $('.gridElement').click(function(e){
  handlePlayerClick(e);
 });

}

function handlePlayerClick(e){

 if(gameOn == false){

  if(xWins == true && drawGame == false){
  } else if(xWins == false && drawGame == false){
  } else if(xWins == false && drawGame == true){
  }

  return;

 }  else {

  if(turn == "player"){

   square = $(e.target);

   if(square.html() == ""){
    square.html(playerSelect);
    turn = "enemy";
    checkForWin();
    if(gameOn == true){
     makeEnemyMove(); 
    }
   } else { } 

  } else {
   if(gameOn == true){
    makeEnemyMove(); 
   }
  }

 }
}

function makeEnemyMove(){
 var chooseNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
 var chooseBox = $('#gridNumber'+chooseNumber);

 if(chooseBox.html() == ''){
  chooseBox.html(aiSelect);
  checkForWin();
  turn ="player";
 } else {
  makeEnemyMove();
 }

}

function checkForWin(){


 for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  var squareVal = $('#gridNumber' + i).html();
  if(squareVal !== ''){
   counter ++;
  }
  gridArray[i] = squareVal;
 }
 
 //--- X Checks for winning ----
 if( (gridArray[0] == 'X' && gridArray[1] == 'X' && gridArray[2] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[3] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[5] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[6] == 'X' && gridArray[7] == 'X' && gridArray[8] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'X' && gridArray[3] == 'X' && gridArray[6] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[1] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[7] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'X' && gridArray[5] == 'X' && gridArray[8] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[8] == 'X') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'X' && gridArray[4] == 'X' && gridArray[6] == 'X') ) 
 { 
  gameOn = false; 
  xWins = true;
  $('#winnerContainer').append('<div id="winnerText">X WINS!</div>');
 }

 //--- Y Checks for winning ----
 if( (gridArray[0] == 'O' && gridArray[1] == 'O' && gridArray[2] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[3] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[5] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[6] == 'O' && gridArray[7] == 'O' && gridArray[8] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'O' && gridArray[3] == 'O' && gridArray[6] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[1] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[7] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'O' && gridArray[5] == 'O' && gridArray[8] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[0] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[8] == 'O') ||
  (gridArray[2] == 'O' && gridArray[4] == 'O' && gridArray[6] == 'O') )
 { 
  gameOn = false; 
  xWins = false;
  $('#winnerContainer').append('<div id="winnerText">O WINS!</div>');
 }

 if(counter == 9 && gameOn == true){
  drawGame = true;
  gameOn = false;
 } else {counter = 0;}

 if(gameOn == false && drawGame == false){
  if(xWins == true){
  } else {
  }
  return;
 }

}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #338f51;
 font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;


}

#title{
 color: #fbd242;
 font-size: 120px;

 margin-top: 10px;
}

#textContainer{
 color: #fbd242;
 font-size: 40px;

 margin-top: 20%;


}

.chooseButton{

 display: inline-block;

 font-size: 120px;

 border-radius: 10px;

 padding-top:10px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;


 background-color: #d81f70;
}

#gridContainer{
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;

 background-color: #ef529c;
 border-radius: 10px; 

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#gridContainer > div{

 color: #fbd242;
 font-size: 140px;
 background-color: #d81f70;

 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;

 display: inline-block;

 width: 120px; height: 120px;
 vertical-align:top;

 border: 1px solid #d81f70;
}



#replay{

 color: #fbd242;

 width: 20px;

 display:block;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.gridElement{
 display: inline-flex !important;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container text-center">

  <div id="title">
   TIC-TAC-TOE
  </div>

  <div id="textContainer">

  </div>



 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the line height of the `#gridContainer > div`, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/34/

```
#gridContainer > div {
    color: #fbd242;
    font-size: 140px;
    background-color: #d81f70;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #d81f70;
    line-height: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple fix would be changing the font-size in the grid container ID to 100px instead of 140px. That would centre the X and O elements correctly.